# Private route using React, React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to make authenticated route using react hooks, with the snippet below, it appears when i refreshed the page while the token is available it doesn't get picked up in the useEffect at the first render. What i'm doing wrong here

```js
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const context = useContext(AuthStateContext)
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      context.setLogin()
    }
    console.log("TOKEN ->", token)
  }, [])
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (
        context.isAuthenticated ?
          <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `context.setLogin()` will set `context.isAuthenticated` to `true`. If that's the case, then it explains.

Callback function of `useEffect(callback)` is always called asynchronously **after** each render. As of first render, `setLogin()` is only called **after** value of `isAuthenticated` is read, which at the time of accessing should be `false`.

So render logic goes to the second branch `<Redirect />` which immediately takes user to other place.

To achieve this, you can defer the rendering util state of `isAuthenticated` is decided.

(Here, I assume you want to check and set `isAuthenticated` **once** early up in the rendering tree, then broadcast the `isAuthenticated` through `AuthStateContext` object for other parts of the app to notice.)

I suggest this pattern:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const context = useContext(AuthStateContext)
  const [authChecked, setAuthChecked] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) context.setLogin()
    setAuthChecked(true)
    console.log("TOKEN ->", token)
  }, [])

  if (!authChecked) return null  // <-- the trick! 

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (
        context.isAuthenticated ?
          <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Side note, if `context.setLogin()` only asynchronously sets the state of `isAuthenticated`, then you need to add in a callback or promise pattern like

```
context.setLogin(() => setAuthChecked(true))
// or 
context.setLogin().then(() => setAuthChecked(true))
```

Comment: Yes isAuthenticated is boolean, and thanks that worked....appreciate the help.